# Cast to Implemented Class

Tags: java, class, classcastexception

So, I'm working in Java, Trying to cast a `java.sql.ResultSet` to my own class `MyResultSet`

Here is the code:
MyResultSet.java

```
public class MyResultSet implements java.sql.ResultSet{
     //There are a bunch of Implemented Methods here. None of them have any custom code, They are all unchanged. Just didn't want to put huge code in here.
}
```

The code I'm trying to use to cast it

```
ResultSet r = getResultSet();
return (MyResultSet)r;
```

Whenever I run this, I get a "ClassCastException".

Could someone explain to me how to cast to an Implemented Class?..

Comment: What is the return type of `getResultSet()` ?

Comment: Well what's `getResultSet()`?

Comment: Probably `java.sql.ResultSet`

Comment: it's `java.sql.ResultSet`. It's just example code.

Comment: Seems you have to read some theory about classes and inheritance =) You can't cast any class to your implementation in java.

Comment: Alright, Well, Thank you all for your help. Is there any other way to do this?.. I'm returning a `ResultSet` from a `PreparedStatement` and I'd like it to be my class returned instead of the default `java.sql.ResultSet`..

Comment: You should create your own Wrapper class (most probably `MyresultSet`) .

Comment: @VishalK, how would I do that?

Comment: `public class MyResultSet implements java.sql.ResultSet{ private ResultSet thisIsTheWrappedResultSet; }`

Comment: It can be done as follows:Create a constructor in `MyresultSet` class and in that pass the object of `ResultSet` obtained. Thereafter you can add various property or functionality to the values obtained from that `resultSe`t object according to your convinience.

Comment: You could get help from this site http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-wrapper-classes-on-the-fly-with-java-dynamic-proxies/5054393 about creating wrapper class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast. The `getResultSet()` will give you an implementation of `java.sql.ResultSet`, which is apparently **not yours**, but belongs to the Java implementation.

If you want to use your methods, you can *delegate* the calls:

```
public class MyResultSet implements ResultSet{
private ResultSet orig;
public MyResultSet(ResultSet orig) {
    this.orig = orig;
}

// do delegations, 1000 methods like this
public String getString(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return orig.getString(columnIndex);
}
// your own methods can come here
}
```

In Eclipse, you can generate the code for delegated methods, don't have to write them one by one. Just create the private field, and do *RightClick - Source - Generate Delegate Methods...*

This technique is called *wrapping*. You wrapped the original object into your one, adding extra functionality.

Now you can call:

```
ResultSet originalresultset = ...;
MyResultSet myresultset = new MyResultSet(originalresultset);
```

Answer (score 5):

An example of what you are trying to do:

```
public interface Animal { } // in your case java.sql.ResultSet

public class Dog implements Animal { } // in your case r

public class Cat implements Animal { } // in your case MyResultSet
```

Later on

```
Animal a = getAnimal(); // returns a Dog
Cat c = (Cat) a; // ClassCastException - Can't cast a Dog to a Cat.
```

You are trying to cast a `Dog` to a `Cat`, but that won't work, because a `Cat` is not a `Dog`.

Comment: @Dukeling: You have my +1 for also proposing a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, That helps a lot. I now know how to use Delegation, And that should solve my problem. Thanks to @GaborSch

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `getResultSet()` returns a class that implements `java.sql.ResultSet`, but this doesn't mean that you can cast to another class that implements it. That's not how inheritance works.

```
       ResultSet
       /       \
MyResultSet  What getResultSet returns
```

When you have a class of a given type, you can only cast it up or down in the inheritance tree, not up, then down in a different direction.

Options:

- If you know what `getResultSet()` returns (I mean the class at the lowest level of inheritance), you can have `MyResultSet` inherit off of that.
- Have a wrapper class that has a `ResultSet` member and that calls the applicable method in that member. Something like:

  ```
  class MyResultSet
  {
    private ResultSet resultSet;
    public MyResultSet(ResultSet resultSet1) { resultSet = resultSet1; }
    public doSomething() { resultSet.doSomething(); }
  }
  ```