# How to implement delegate pattern (like in objective-c ) in java

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

I looked at an example where delegation pattern is explained for java. Didn't find much use for it (excuse the ignorance) as i feel it lacks the flexibility in objective-c. Is there way to dynamically set the delegate object as one can do in objective-c. Isn't that the whole point of delegation? My knowledge of java is very preliminary , so please explain a bit in detail.

Comment: The [Java AWT Event architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/1.3/designspec/events.html) employs the delegation model. You might want to give that linked doc a read.

Comment: @Perception: i checked the link. In the code example given, isn't necessary that the delegate passed should always be of the type 'App'. This is what i meant by flexibility. Or am i completely wrong about the App object being the delegate?

Comment: A few days ago here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963740/cast-to-implemented-class/14963939#14963939 I sketched the delegation pattern with an example, you could check it.

Comment: @Rakesh, it helps if you think of `App` in this context as being the delegate protocol (its not exact, but close enough). You will find that the Java AWT event model employs alot of interfaces (`MouseListener`, `WindowListener`, `ButtonListener` etc). These are basically the protocols that an Objective-C delegate typically conforms to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are many ways ways to implement delegation pattern in Java, but probably none which feels like a built-in.

Take a look at the [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Complex). Your basic option is to manually **implement an interface**, and then simply forward the calls **to a concrete instance** which you can change during run-time as much as you wish.

Now depending on what tools you have and can use, you can make this **forwarding** more automatic. One idea, is to use aspect-oriented programming, like AspectJ.

Having an aspect compiler (or runtime) you could utilize annotations and come up with a simple extension to the language:

```
class Person {
  @Delegate Animal animal;
  ...
}
```

You'd then have to write an aspect that finds `@Delegate`s and automatically adds forwarding methods in the class'es (eg. `Person`) interface.

**If** you are able to use [a more groovy JVM language](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), then you wouldn't even have to write a single line of code, because such languages have delegates in the standard library:

You can have a look [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Delegate+transformation), to see how it's done in Groovy. (essentialy exactly like the `Person` example syntax I came up with... but built-in!)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you fake a functional idiom in Java.  Yes, it's hideous.  If you want elegant functional idioms, use a language that doesn't treat functions like red-headed step-children.  If you want more compile time safety, you can of course use more specific interface definitions so that you don't get IndexOutOfBounds and ClassCastException all over the place from programming errors.

```
public interface DelegatedFunction<T> {

T call(Object... args);

}

public class DoesSomeDelegatedTask {

  private List<DelegatedFunction<String>> delegatedFunctions = new ArrayList<>(1);

  public void addFunction(DelegatedFunction<String> function) {
    delegatedFunctions.add(function);
  }

  public void execute() {
    for (DelegatedFunction<String> function: delegatedFunctions) {
      System.out.println(function(something, someotherthing, whatever));
    }
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DoesSomeDelegateTask doer = new DoesSomeDelegatedTask();
    doer.addFunction(new DelegatedFunction<String> () {
      @Override
      public String call(Object... args) {
        return ((SomeThings) args[0]).whatever((SomeOtherThing) args[1]//you get the idea
      }
    }
    doer.execute();
  }
}
```